# Laravel 5.4 Eloquent relationship sorting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two database tables called deliverables, and deliverable_version.

> Deliverable hasMany Deliverable_Version.

**Deliverable** has id column, and the model has a function to get the most recent version:

```
public function getRecentVersion()
    {
        $deliverable_version_max = $this->versions()->max('version');

        $deliverable_version = DeliverableVersion::where([
            'version'=>$deliverable_version_max,
            'deliverable_ID'=>$this->id,
        ])->first();

        return $deliverable_version;
    }
```

**Deliverable_version** table has id, deliverable_ID, title, message, deadline, version, created_at, updated_at.

How I would perform an operation where I can:

1. Get all deliverables and the most recent version associated with the deliverable.
2. Sort the deliverables by it by the columns of the deliverable_version table (updated_at)
3. Paginate the result?

Here is my attempt at it, which isn't working because it selects **all** the versions when I join the tables, not just the recent version:

```
$deliverables = Accounts::find($owner_account_ID)->deliverables();
    $deliverables = $deliverables->join('deliverable_version', 'deliverable.id', '=', 'deliverable_version.deliverable_ID');
    $deliverables = $deliverables->search($search);
    $deliverables = $deliverables->orderBy('deliverable_version.updated_at', 'desc');
    $deliverables = $deliverables->paginate(4);
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: add your model file to get better answer.

Comment: okay, the model files has been added.

Answer (score 0):

```
in Accounts module add:

 public function deliverable_version(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\deliverable_version');
    }

in controller:

    enter code here

$deliverables = Accounts::find($owner_account_ID)->deliverables()>with('deliverable_version');
foreach($deliverables as $deliverable){
// last version
$deliverable = $deliverables->deliverable_version->last();
```

}

Comment: Okay I don't have a problem finding the last version. The problem is finding the recent versions, sorting it by the "updated_at" column, and then paginating it.

Comment: return $this->hasMany('App\deliverable_version')->orderBy('updated_at');

Answer (score 0):

```
in Accounts module add:

 public function deliverable_version(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\deliverable_version')->orderBy('update_at');
    }

in controller:


$deliverables = Accounts::find($owner_account_ID)->deliverables()>with('deliverable_version');
foreach($deliverables as $deliverable){
// last version
$deliverable = $deliverables->deliverable_version->last();
```